# How do I access files in VM Fusion (running Ubuntu) from the (Mac) host machine?

Tags: macos, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-fusion

I'm running VMWare Fusion on my mac (OS X Lion). I saved a file there that I'd like to view on the host machine. How can I access this file?

VMWare is running an Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit server image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMWare provides a mounter for their disk image, so you can double click on the vmdk file and it should be mounted automatically.

Your real problem is that OS X has no built-in support for the ext file system, but you can easily find third party tools online. You can either download pre-compiled packages or use macport/brew to compile your own.

Comment: didn't quite follow you. what is the vhd file?

Comment: i don't see anything when i run `sudo find / -name "*vhd*"` that looks like it belongs to the vm.

Comment: Sorry. It should be .vmdk file instead of vhd. You can find it in your virtual machine "file" which is actually an package that you can open using the context menu.